# How do I run all my PHPUnit tests?

Tags: php, linux, unit-testing, ubuntu, phpunit

I have script called Script.php and tests for it in Tests/Script.php, but when I run phpunit Tests it does not execute any tests in my test file. How do I run all my tests with phpunit?

PHPUnit 3.3.17, PHP 5.2.6-3ubuntu4.2, latest Ubuntu

**Output:**

```
$ phpunit Tests
PHPUnit 3.3.17 by Sebastian Bergmann.
Time: 0 seconds
OK (0 tests, 0 assertions)
```

And here are my script and test files:

**Script.php**

```
<?php  
function returnsTrue() {  
    return TRUE;  
}  
?>
```

**Tests/Script.php**

```
<?php  
require_once 'PHPUnit/Framework.php';  
require_once 'Script.php'  

class TestingOne extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase  
{

    public function testTrue()
    {
        $this->assertEquals(TRUE, returnsTrue());
    }

    public function testFalse()
    {
        $this->assertEquals(FALSE, returnsTrue());
    }
}

class TestingTwo extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase  
{

    public function testTrue()  
    {  
        $this->assertEquals(TRUE, returnsTrue());  
    }

    public function testFalse()
    {
        $this->assertEquals(FALSE, returnsTrue());
    }
}  
?>
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I created following **phpunit.xml** and now atleast I can do *phpunit --configuration phpunit.xml* in my root directory to run the tests located in Tests/

```
<phpunit backupGlobals="false"
         backupStaticAttributes="false"
         syntaxCheck="false">
  <testsuites>
    <testsuite name="Tests">
      <directory suffix=".php">Tests</directory>
    </testsuite>
  </testsuites>
</phpunit>
```

Answer (score 63):

Php test's filename must end with Test.php

`phpunit  mydir`  will run all scripts named `xxxxTest.php` in directory mydir

(looks likes it's not described in the phpunit documentation)

Comment: Its not a must. You can specify --test-suffix "TestCase.php" if your test files are ending with "TestCase.php", but by default phpunit will only accept suffix as "Test.php" when we are not specifying a suffix in the command line

Answer (score 11):

I think forPHPUnit to decide to automatically run it it must follow a filename convention: somethingTest.php.

Answer (score 3):

You think they would have documented this. I just looked through the manual, and they say you can pass a directory, but not really how to do it.

Perhaps your class name has to match the basename (everything but the ".php") of your test scripts filename?

Answer (score -6):

```
<?php
//Files required for phpunit test
require_once 'PHPUnit/Framework.php';
//Knowing the drupal environment
require_once './includes/bootstrap.inc';     //initialize the Drupal framework
//Loading the drupal bootstrap
drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);
//Helper file
include_once 'helper.inc';
//Including inc file of addresses module
include_once(module_load_include('inc','addresses_user','addresses_user'));

class addresses_test extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {

protected $uid;

protected function setUp()
{
    $this->uid = 1;
}
```